# highcharts-ng: Cannot read property 'setExtremes' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

Suddenly **highcharts-ng** module started throwing out quite a strange error.

[image]

I did not touch this part of the code and I don't use **setExtremes** property.

Error Line 92:

[image]

If somebody already faced with such kind of problem I really appreciate your help.

Comment: check your chart config, cross check if you have used setExtremes for x or Y axis. share fiddle for better understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new bug introduced in 0.0.9 and only partially fixed in 0.0.10.

It will be fixed in a 0.0.11 shortly. In the meantime if in your chart config you define a yAxis it will work:

```
yAxis: {
      events: {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with **highcharts-ng** version update from **0.0.8** to **0.0.10**

So we decided to do the simplest solution for now and downgrade to **0.0.8**.

If you know how to solve the problem with new version - please post it here.

Comment: How about posting this issue on the github bug tracker?